# Solr - How to match a document?

Tags: php, solr

I have a table containing articles and I want to match the current article with all the articles in the database and find out the match percentage.How can I do this in Solr with PHP. I have already Indexed the data in solr. I am using only two fields in schema.xml

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 

<field name="body" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Is there something that I could do by passing the id of the current article and all the matched articles are displayed.

Comment: you can add documents: <add></add>, or conversion JSON. In PHP show link: http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/add-spectacular-search-with-solr/

Comment: Can you please elaborate how can I add the document, the link has explained all the things quite nicely but doesn't show how to match large data.

Comment: Look into More Like This: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis